# How can I make the elements in my arrays sub arrays position vertically? Ruby

Tags: ruby

```
@bingo_board = Array.new(5) {Array(5.times.map{rand(1..100)})}

B  I  N  G  O

0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  3  4
```

I am trying to get the elements in the sub arrays of `@bingo_board` to position vertically, but with each array horizontally aligned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT**

Maybe I missunderstood the question, to transpose printing the array (if this what you want), just use print by first loop, then the second:

```
bb = [[ 4,  2, 74, 97, 76], 
      [67, 54, 61, 84, 31], 
      [68, 56, 49, 57, 69], 
      [61, 92, 71, 77, 22], 
      [99,  8, 89, 11, 88]] # just an example
puts ('%3s ' * 5) % 'BINGO'.split('')
5.times do |y|
  5.times { |x| print "%3i " % bb[x][y] } 
  # access by x (column) then y (row)
  # normally its by row first then column
  puts
end

# the output:
  B   I   N   G   O 
  4  67  68  61  99 
  2  54  56  92   8 
 74  61  49  71  89 
 97  84  57  77  11 
 76  31  69  22  88 

# just for knowledge, when accessed by row then column first (bb[y][x]), the output would be:
  4   2  74  97  76 
 67  54  61  84  31 
 68  56  49  57  69 
 61  92  71 100  22 
 99   8  89  11  88
```

**OLD ANSWER**

Just use map to fetch all columns, for example:

```
def get_col bb, y
  bb.map{|x| x[y]}
end
# test: 
bingo_board = Array.new(5) {Array(5.times.map{rand(1..100)})}
#=> [[70,  4, 31, 46, 91], 
#    [76, 47, 16, 80, 37], 
#    [61, 72,  7, 10, 49], 
#    [44, 62, 98, 54, 86], 
#    [90, 43, 45, 85, 57]]
get_col bingo_board, 0
#=> [70, 76, 61, 44, 90]
get_col bingo_board, 1
#=> [4, 47, 72, 62, 43]
get_col bingo_board, 2
#=> [31, 16, 7, 98, 45]
get_col bingo_board, 3
#=> [46, 80, 10, 54, 85]
get_col bingo_board, 4
#=> [91, 37, 49, 86, 57]
```

It's always better to create a class to do so:

```
class BingoBoard
  N = 5
  def initialize
    @board = Array.new(N) {Array(N.times.map{rand(1..100)})}
  end
  def get_col n
    raise "invalid column: #{n}" if n<0 or n>=N
    @board.map{|x| x[n]}
  end
  def get_row n
    raise "invalid row: #{n}" if n<0 or n>=N
    @board[n]
  end
end
# test:
bb = BingoBoard.new
#=> #<BingoBoard:0x0000000215f6b0 @board=[
#     [ 4,  8, 96, 49, 30], 
#     [21, 49, 43, 73, 96], 
#     [83, 73, 10, 27, 54], 
#     [51, 89, 10, 31, 20], 
#     [47, 58, 44, 78, 18]]>
bb.get_row 0
#=> [4, 8, 96, 49, 30]
bb.get_col 0
#=> [4, 21, 83, 51, 47]
bb.get_col 4
#=> [30, 96, 54, 20, 18]
```

Comment: Yes that worked my friend! Thank you for the extra knowledge as well, your words were truly appreciated!

Comment: When I try to Vote-Up your answer it tells me I must have a reputation of 15 before I am aloud to do that. As soon as my reputation is up I will be sure to come back and vote your comment up. Thanks for letting me know as well!